# link Redirect from php

Tags: php, jquery, anchor

Dear  all

I have database of website link, it list out in  main file ,when i try to click that link it get to redirect on that database link.
my code is:

```
file: test.php

 <?php
     // getting from database
     echo '<li onclick=\"window.location='.$result->website.'\">
           <a href="#">'.$result->option.'</a></li>';
 ?>

The Main.html calls that test.php
while ajax

$.post("test.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){

});
```

how to do it?
any idea Is it possible with serverside script? whats wrong with my php code?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Perhaps post more of the code you are using and what you would like your final HTML to look like when it is sent to the users browser.

Comment: <?php
$link="www.google.com";
echo "<a href='#' onclick=window.location='$link'>Click here</a>";
?> the above code not works why its not to redirect google if you solve this enoough for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not work for invalid URLs. www.google.com is not an URL, just a domain name. So skip the silly Javascript links, instead use:

```
 echo "<li><a href=\"$link\">$link</a></li>\n";
```

And your Javascript success function seems somewhat empty, so instead use .load() like:

```
 $("ul").load("links.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited after venkat's comment:-**

According to your last comment, the code you have problems with is the following:-

```
<?php
$link="www.google.com";
echo "<a href='#' onclick=window.location='$link'>Click here</a>";
?>
```

This above code should actually be the following:-

```
<?php
$link = "http://www.google.com/";
echo '<a href="'.$link.'">Click here</a>';
?>
```

The reason for adding the "http://" string is that the variable "$link" is going to be used as an HTTP URL, which requires mentioning of this "http://" string, mainly because of the protocol to be used by the browser. In this case, the protocol is HTTP.
Always remember that for any URL, there must be a string "http://" at the beginning of the URL string, when stored in either a database / variable.

Coming back to the code in your question, which was:-

```
<?php
// getting from database

echo '<li onclick=\"window.location='.$result->website.'\"><a href="#">'.$result->option.'</a></li>';
?>
```

Now here the position of "`window.location`" is not totally correct. It should have been in "href" attribute of "a" element, instead of putting it in "onclick" attribute of "li" element.
So the code should actually be:-

```
<?php
// getting from database
echo '<li><a href="'.$result->website.'">'.$result->option.'</a></li>';
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your code getting database seemsto be not work however i fix the problem!

Comment: @venkat - can you please post the fix of the problem? Also it would be good if you can point as to where my code is wrong, so that I can correct it too. Thanks

Comment: your code echo '<li><a href="window.location=\''.$result->website.'\';">'.$result->option.'</a></li>'; 
wrong.Hope i too try the solution ,However mario tricks helps  me

Comment: @venkat- This code does not give me any error, although you need to be careful when using quotes - both single & double quotes - in PHP along with variables. This is main area, where many programmers tend to slip, if not careful, even I was as a fresher. Thanks